# mobile emulation with storybook react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swipe, touchscreen, storybook

I'm trying to test my touchscreen swipe event listeners on a react component built with storybook, and I can't seem to get proper mobile emulation to work. The style changes I have attached to window width breakpoints work upon physically resizing the window, but when viewing the iframe mode in either the chrome device emulator, or on my phone, it just looks like a tiny version of the desktop site. It doesnt seem to work with my swipe animations either. I've done tons of googling on this, and all I've managed to find is a storybook add-on to manipulate the viewport (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/addon-viewport). I'm pretty new to developing for mobile-only options like touchscreen swipe, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you provide some more details of your problem, like your component code, how you call the component within storybook code, or a screenshot of your emulation?

Comment: I'm having the same problem though I'm not concerned about gestures, just responsiveness, so thanks for the addon-viewport link. I think it might work for me.

Answer (score 1):

i discovered that the problem was with meta tags. to get mobile emulation to work, you have to in the `.storybook` folder, add a file named `preview-head.html` and in the file put `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` then to get the emulation to work correctly, view the component as an iframe.